# Error running Lagom hello-world example

Tags: java, scala, lagom

While trying to run the Lagom Hello World example, I'm getting the following error:

```
    > runAll
[info] Starting Kafka
[info] Starting Cassandra
.SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
.......
[info] Cassandra server running at 127.0.0.1:4000
[info] Service locator is running at http://localhost:8000
[info] Service gateway is running at http://localhost:9000
SLF4J: io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache
SLF4J: The following set of substitute loggers may have been accessed
SLF4J: during the initialization phase. Logging calls during this
SLF4J: phase were not honored. However, subsequent logging calls to these
SLF4J: loggers will work as normally expected.
SLF4J: See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#substituteLogger
SLF4J: io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache
[error] c.l.l.i.s.r.ServiceRegistration - Service name=[hello-stream}] couldn't register itself to the service locator.
org.asynchttpclient.exception.RemotelyClosedException: Remotely closed
[warn] c.l.l.i.p.c.ServiceLocatorSessionProvider - Could not find Cassandra contact points, due to: Remotely closed
[warn] c.l.l.i.s.r.ServiceRegistryServiceLocator - The service locator replied with an error when looking up the service name=[cas_native] address
org.asynchttpclient.exception.RemotelyClosedException: Remotely closed
[error] c.l.l.i.s.r.ServiceRegistration - Service name=[hello}] couldn't register itself to the service locator.
org.asynchttpclient.exception.RemotelyClosedException: Remotely closed
[info] Service hello-impl listening for HTTP on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:57797
[info] Service hello-stream-impl listening for HTTP on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:58322
[info] (Services started, press enter to stop and go back to the console...)
```

Does anybody have an idea, Why?

Comment: Are you using the maven or sbt hello world project of lagom?

Comment: SBT. I am running the following example give in documentation. https://github.com/lagom/lagom-scala.g8

Comment: Please post the _complete_ output. There might be a clue earlier in the logs. Are there any port conflicts?

Comment: I have edited the question with complete logs. I don't see any port confilicts.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have anything else running in ports 4000, 8000, 9000? Maybe you have another sbt instance running. Another possibility is that the internal projects got corrupted somehow. Try removing your `target` dir and running `sbt runAll` again.

Comment: Are you using a proxy? Could it be that requests to your localhost are being routed through the proxy?

Comment: @TimMoore: The example magically worked later, may be the issue was another sbt instance running in parallel.

Comment: Hi, how to identify another SBT instance running in parallel ? I still have this problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was because of there were two sbt instances in the system (the first one was installed by IDE). I have deleted another one and now it works